# Windows Servers Commandline/PowerShell How to capture, CPU utilization as there in TaskManager?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, cpu-usage

For Monitoring windows 2012/2008 performance,

I need to capture CPU utilization along with top 3 process names consuming CPU at the most, on Windows 2012/2008 Servers over command line.

I've tried the following, but none of them matches as with the TaskManger output.

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time"
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor
typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

Is there any way to Capture CPU utilization which will match the TaskManager output...?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Powershell Code get get the processor utilization information.

```
Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
```

[Here is an explanation of the data returned](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-time-and-process-processor-time.aspx)

You can also run `Get-Counter` to get memory, disk and network counters.

Here is the code to get the top 3 processes by CPU utilization:

```
Get-Process | Sort CPU -descending | Select -first 3 -Property ID,ProcessName,CPU | format-table
```

Comment: Get-Process -> CPU(s)  is it the CPU utilization of a process in second since its start..?